# Glide cannot load picture from the Room DB. Load failed for null with size [0x0]

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-glide

Im trying to load image in RecyclerView with Glide.
User need to choose the picture in parentClass, after that, picture would be saved in RoomDB and loaded into RecyclerView, but Glide says

```
2021-09-23 18:23:30.321 10414-10414/com.example.rempractice W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [0x0]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model
```

parentClass listener

```java
        ARB.contRem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(ARB.remText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ARB.err.setText("errCode");
                }
                else if(ARB.dateFromCalendar.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    ARB.err.setText("errCode");
                }
                else {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ARB.addImageRem.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Uri uri = getImageUri(getContext(), bitmap);
                    list.add(uri.toString());

                    ARVM.addReminder(ARB.remText.getText().toString(),
                            ARB.dateFromCalendar.getText().toString(),
                            false,
                            list);

                    Navigation.findNavController(v).popBackStack();
                }
            }
        });
```

adapterClass

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull reminderViewHolder holder, int position) {


        GlideApp.with(hostFragment).load(rems.get(position).getImages()).apply(new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .fitCenter()).into(holder.binding.imageView);

        holder.binding.textrow.setText(rems.get(position).getTextRem());
        holder.binding.daterow.setText(rems.get(position).getDateRem());
        holder.binding.isdone.setChecked(rems.get(position).isDone());

    }
```

DTO class

```
    @Override
    public List<String> getImages() {
        if (super.getImages() == null || super.getImages().isEmpty()) {
            super.setImages(new Gson().fromJson(this.images, List.class));
        }
        return super.getImages();
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        super.setImages(Collections.singletonList(images));
        this.images = new Gson().toJson(images);
    }
```

Glide implementations

```
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Photo which i expect
[image: Photo which i expect]

Photo which i get
[image: Photo which i get]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a override method in DTO class.

before

```java
    public void setImages(String images) {
        super.setImages(Collections.singletonList(images));
        this.images = new Gson().toJson(images);
    }
```

after

```java
    @Override
    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
        super.setImages(images);
        this.images = new Gson().toJson(images);
    }
```